# can please someone explain the working of bind function for this example from eloquent

Tags: javascript

isInSet requires two arguments, but binds passes only theSet as first argument. I am not able to figure out how bind method works in this case

```
function isInSet(set , person) {
return set.indexOf(person.name) > -1;//checks for existence of person.name in theSet
}
console.log(ancestry .filter(function(person) {
return isInSet( theSet , person) ;
}) ) ;
// ! [{ name : " Maria van B r u s s e l " , ...} ,
// { name : " Carel H a v e r b e k e " , ...}]
console.log(ancestry.filter(isInSet.bind(null, theSet)))  ;//**how does this work?**
// !... same result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the text from the book a few times and compare the unbound and the bound version.

Calling `.bind()` on a function, return a new function, with some of the arguments already filled in. The isInSet function, expects two parameters: the set to filter, and a person having a name.

The `.filter()` method of an array, expects one parameter, namely the function to which each element of the array has to be sent to.
So when you look to the unbound version, you see that the filter function used, just returns `isInSet(theSet, person)`.

So to make the two compatible, we `.bind()` to create a new function with only one parameter left (namely 'person'), that is bound to theSet. So every time this new function returned by bind gets called, it will use theSet as it's first parameter and will expect only one parameter, 'person'.
Here, person, the second parameter of the original isInSet function we didn't bind, is used as the first and only parameter of the bound function.

So we have exactly what we need after using the bind. A function that will take a 'person' as a parameters and will always look inside the same array (theSet).

If you read the docs for `.bind()`, you see that it accepts a variable list of arguments. The first argument is the 'this' argument. So if you have a function that uses 'this' inside it and you want to bind it to eg. an object, you can use the 1st parameter. Eg. `myFunc.bind( objectToCallUpon, firstArg, secondArg );`
Since we don't actually use the 'this' argument in the isInSet() function, we just pass 'null' as the 'this' value.

All the other parameters used are the arguments of isInSet you want to make 'fixed'. Since we want the first parameter to always be theSet, we bind that value.

If the isInSet function would accept two parameters, you would use:
`isInSet.bind( null, theSet, secondParameter );`

Answer (score 1):

`bind()` creates a new function from the function that it is called on. It sets the `this` keyword in the newly created function to be the first argument that you pass it (if `null` is passed, then it does not overwrite the default `this` keyword). You can also pass in extra arguments to `bind()` and if you do, they will always be inserted into the new function. So for instance, let's say you have a `sum` function that takes 2 arguments.

```
function sum (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Now we could create a new function from this using `bind()` and always pass in one argument.

```
var boundSum = sum.bind(null, 2);
```

This will always bind 2 as the first argument in the `sum()` function. Now anytime you call that `boundSum()` function, it will only take *one* argument, as the 2 is already bound.

```
boundSum(3); // <-- this would return 5
```

Your example is using a similar principle. Because you are calling `isInSet.bind(null, theSet)` it is always binding `theSet` to the first parameter passed in the `isInSet` function. However, it is still missing the second parameter. The reason why it works is because you are putting that inside of an `ancestry.filter()` function. `filter()` essentially loops over an array and passes each element to the function inside of it ([check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)). So therefore, each element in the `ancestry` array is getting passed to that bound function, which makes it the second parameter of `isInSet()`.